# Паттерн "Посетитель". Java

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

В первый раз реализую, и что-то не заработало.

```
public interface FieldVisitor {
    Object visit(Field field);
}
```

А это методы из реализации:

```
private FieldVisitor factory = new FieldVisitor() {
    public Object visit(PresetField presetField) {
        ....
    }

    public Object visit(StringField stringField) {
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public Object visit(Field field) {
        System.out.println(field.getClass());
        ....
    }
};
```

Вызываю так:

```
public Node getFieldFor(Field field) {
    return (Node) factory.visit(field);
}
```

Видно что приходят объекты разных классов:

```
class com.dma.params.model.field.PresetField
class com.dma.params.model.field.PresetField
class com.dma.params.model.field.NumberField
class com.dma.params.model.field.NumberField
class com.dma.params.model.field.StringField
class com.dma.params.model.field.BooleanField
```

Однако попадаю как видно только в метод для суперкласса. В общем, как я понял, какой тип указателя, такая функция вызывается. Я могу как то изменить это поведение? Чтобы вызывалась функция для фактического типа или я где-то тупанул с паттерном?

Comment: По шаблону не скажу, но по коду вижу, ты вызываешь метод `visit(Field field)`, это значит, что полиморфизм будет **только** для параметра типа `Field`, а методы `visit(PresetField), visit(StringField)` являются абсолютно самостоятельными, перегрузка - не есть переопределение.

Comment: У Вас есть перегруженный метод visit(...), Вы вызываете его `factory.visit(field)`, где `field` – объект класса `Field`, соответственно и вызывается метод `visit(Field field)`. А суперкласса я вообще тут не вижу.

Comment: Я пробовал в интерфейсе указать перегруженные версии для всех типов входных параметров (то есть не только перегружать но и переопределять каждый вариант - эффекта ноль. Да и не играет это роли в данном случае, ибо вызываю я этот метод сразу с конкретной реализации, а не с интерфейса.

Comment: Забыл указать, Field и есть суперкласс для всех )

Comment: не важно, суперкласс он или нет, важно, что вызывается метод для типа Field, для этого типа и вызовется, не важно, какой сабкласс ты туда передаёшь - вызовется метод именно для Field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что всё совершенно не так.

Во-первых интерфейс визитёра должен объявлять методы для всех классов иерархии

```
public interface FieldVisitor {
    Object visit(PresetField field);
    Object visit(StringField field);
    ...
}
```

Во-вторых родоначальник иерархии объявляет абстрактный метод accept, в котором принимается визитёр

```
class Field {
    ...
    public abstract void accept(FieldVisitor visitor);
    ...
}
```

В-третьих конкретные такие потомки реализуют/переопределяют метод-акцептор таким образом, чтобы вызывался метод визитёра для нужного (своего) класса

```
class StringField {
    ...
    @Override
    public abstract void accept(FieldVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this); // вызов visit(StringField field)
    }
    ...
}
```

Наконец визитёр может посетить иерархию, предварительно реализовав интерфейс визитёра вызовом акцептора

```
...
field.accept(new FieldVisitor() {
    @Override
    Object visit(PresetField field) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    Object visit(StringField field) {
        ...
    }

});
...
```

Благодаря полиморфизму вызывается accept конкретного класса, который в свою очередь вызывает "свой" перегруженный метод визитёра.

Comment: Ага, вроде дошло, сейчас попробую, спасибо большое )

Comment: Отлично, теперь до меня наконец-то дошел этот паттерн ) Спасибо )